# XCode Storyboard: how to create a segue when the segue trigger is not on storyboard

Tags: xcode, storyboard, uistoryboardsegue

So I started playing with storyboards in XCode 4.3.2. I started with the Master-Detail application (split view application for iPad). In the detail view (named `DetailVC`) I have a view where I displayed an array of custom views.

The custom views (named `GridView`) have a tap gesture recognizer which is supposed to handle the tap event on each custom view. Tapping a `GridView` pushes a view controller show some search results (named `SearchResultsVC`).

With `GridView` created in a separate nib file, and the `DetailVC` and `SearchResultsVC` reside in storyboard, how can I create a push segue with destination `SearchResultsVC`? I just created a segue between DetailVC and SearchResultsVC? Is there someway I can trigger this segue programatically from inside the GridView class when tap gesture is recognized????

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the method where you handle the tap use:

[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"yourSegueIdentifier" sender:self];

In your StoryBoard control drag from your DetailVC to your SearchResultVC and choose what type of segue you would like. Make sure to name your segue identifier the same as the one in the method above in attributes inspector.

I'm gonna try and improve my answer I messed it up I think:

1) In your DetailVC.h create an instance variable for your GridView like this

```
IBOutlet UIView * gridView;
```

also create a getter method and an IBAction for your grid view like this

```
-(UIView *)gridView;
-(IBAction)myGridGotPressed:(id)sender;
```

2)Now in your DetailVC.m implement your methods like this

```
-(UIView *)gridView{
if(!gridView){
[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"GridView" owner:self options:nil];
}
return gridView;
}
```

Also implement your IBAction like this

```
-(IBAction)myGridGotPressed:(id)sender{
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"yourSegueIdentifier" sender:self];
}
```

3) To make this work you need to change the filesOwner class of your GridView to DetailVC and then hook up the outlets and Actions as normal.

I hope that helps.

Comment: the grid view would have to pass the touch back to the DetailVC. UIView subclasses can't perform segues.

Comment: I presumed DetailVC would have the method to handle the touch via IBAction or his own protocol.

Comment: @jrturton - How should I go about passing the touch back to DetailVC? Using delegates - how would I get a reference to DetailVC in that case (views shouldn't know about view controllers, right?)

Comment: @GazLong - thanks a lot. That's what I needed `Changing the file owner`. Just one question - how exactly can that be done? In Interface builder?

Comment: Just hit files owner in the left hand side (scene editor) and change the class from NSObject to your View controller class.